# Unusual ipv6 connection

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have been using some network monitoring tools and they recently flagged up a strange (impossible?) Network connection.

The output was as follows:
[image: Strange output]

Does anyone know what this connection is? The double `::` seems to make it impossible.

Here is another instance of it connecting to an unknown address:
[image: Strange output 2]

Any help with this appreciated.

Comment: The IPv6 address block `fe80::/10` belongs to [Link-Local Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) which can't be forwarded by routers and connectd to any remote server.

Comment: Should these Link-local connections still be happening if ipv6 is off?

Comment: No. If your ISP does not provide IPv6 services you can disable IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 services, as I understand it, are the future of the internet. I thought I remember reading somewhere that internet connections would transfer to IPv6 at some time in the future. Current I have Ipv6 disabled, yet this Link Local Address keeps showing up despite the router I'm using showing me that IPv6 is disabled for my machine. Welp!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double colons basically mean that the space inbetween [those colons are all zeros](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/ipv6-overview-24/index.html) -  so `::` is the same as `:0000:` or `:0000:0000:`. Essentially to convert the short form to a "full" IP address, you'd want to pad out each 16 bit field, and any sets of colons to get the form you expect

`ff02::1:2` is the same as `ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:0002` (which is a bit hard to type.)

According to whois, its a multicast address

```
geek@phoebe ~]$ whois ff02::1:2
[Querying whois.iana.org]
[whois.iana.org]
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

inet6num:     ff00:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/8
descr:        Multicast

remarks:      http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291

source:       IANA
```

Comment: Aha, very helpful! Thank you! `ff02::1:2` translates to a Nigerian address. Is there any way of getting more information out of this ipv6 address?

Comment: I should also add that I have ipv6 disabled. I don't even have an ipv6 address on my router so this connection is very strange.

Comment: ...Nigerian? Just _how_ are you "translating" it? `fe80::` is the link-local address range, while `ff02::1:2` is a local multicast address (specifically "all nearby DHCPv6 servers" multicast). They don't belong to _any_ country nor location.

Comment: https://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ipv6-address/ff02::1:2